# Android Studio shows wrong file contents flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[Here is how my class file looks like on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALYeY.png)

Comment: Check this file from explorer

Comment: thanks deleting android studio cache solved it but one file stile broken

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem some days ago, and could not solve it by android studio. Then I re install flutter again and it was solved.